# Oauth2 Invalid Grant with doorkeeper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

When I try to get a resource from my api, I get an invalid grant.

`invalid_grant: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request,or was issued to another client.`

what could be the issue?

```
  require 'sinatra'
  require 'httparty'
  require 'oauth2'

  enable :sessions

  configure do
    set :callback, 'http://localhost:4567/auth/doorkeeper/callback'
    set :app_id, '7cd423ef68bdc938372d8e290475ea5a85feb550004b77481f99ff0dcba133b1'
    set :app_secret, '46bafd07b5a485240d7fdaedbdbac2a675afabe470f5433b13395f8dcff4e473'
  end

  get '/' do
    oauth_client.auth_code.authorize_url(redirect_uri: settings.callback)
  end

  get '/auth/doorkeeper/callback' do
    if params[:code].nil?
      redirect to('/')
    end

    session[:code] = params[:code]

    redirect to('/get_token')
  end

  get '/get_token' do
    access = oauth_client.auth_code.get_token session[:code], :redirect_uri => settings.callback
    # session[:code]
    access.get('/api/v1/me')
  end

  def oauth_client
    @oauth_client ||= OAuth2::Client.new(settings.app_id, settings.app_secret, site: "http://localhost:3000")
  end
```

Comment: Does your `grant_flows` include `authorization_code`? Have you changed the `authorize_url` or `token_url` from the [defaults](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/master/lib/oauth2/client.rb#L33) ?

edit: dang, just noticed this was over a year old. my b.

Answer (score 0):

If the authorization works already for the first time, then suddenly the error appears, it just means that the token has expired or revoked.

When you have received a valid token before and the error re-appears, just go to your Documents folder, remove the .credentials folder (where your previous token resides), then run the application again to receive a new token.